# String isNullOrEmpty in Java?

Tags: java, string

This surely has been asked before, but <s>[Googling doesn't find it](http://www.google.co.il/search?q=java+string+isnullorempty+site:stackoverflow.com)</s>. Is there, in any of the standard java libraries (including apache/google/...), a static `isNullOrEmpty()` method for `Strings`?

Comment: its not String, it should be Strings,  as an example Strings.isNullOrEmpty()

Answer (score 175, accepted):

- [`StringUtils.isEmpty(str)`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#isEmpty(java.lang.String)) or [`StringUtils.isNotEmpty(str)`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#isNotEmpty(java.lang.String))
- [`StringUtils.isBlank(str)`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#isBlank(java.lang.String)) or [`StringUtils.isNotBlank(str)`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#isNotBlank(java.lang.String))

from Apache [commons-lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/).

The difference between `empty` and `blank` is : a string consisted of whitespaces only is `blank` but isn't `empty`.

I generally prefer using apache-commons if possible, instead of writing my own utility methods, although that is also plausible for simple ones like these.

Comment: I was confused between the distinction between blank and empty, so I looked it up; blank means, "", null, and any amount of whitespace; empty is just "" and null.

Comment: in this case google methods http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Strings.html#isNullOrEmpty(java.lang.String) seems clearer

Comment: New link do Guava doc: http://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Strings.html#isNullOrEmpty-java.lang.String-

Answer (score 108):

If you are doing android development, you can use:

```
TextUtils.isEmpty (CharSequence str)
```

Added in API level 1
Returns true if the string is null or 0-length.

Comment: Dude that is awesome! This is exactly what I was looking for to keep from having to use try catch clauses, much thanks!

Comment: Much love - thank you!

Answer (score 54):

`com.google.common.base.Strings.isNullOrEmpty(String string)` from [Google Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/)

Comment: To add, `isNullOrEmpty` does returns true if the given string just has whitespace(s). What does "empty" means in real world ? Sounds fun to me!

Comment: Actually it returns false... 
  public static boolean isNullOrEmpty(@Nullable String string) {
    return string == null || string.length() == 0; // string.isEmpty() in Java 6
  }

Answer (score 28):

No, which is why so many other libraries have their own copy :)

Answer (score 14):

You can add one

```
public static boolean isNullOrBlank(String param) { 
    return param == null || param.trim().length() == 0;
}
```

I have

```
public static boolean isSet(String param) { 
    // doesn't ignore spaces, but does save an object creation.
    return param != null && param.length() != 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 10):

To check if a string got any characters, ie. not null or whitespaces, check `StringUtils.hasText`-method (if you are using Spring of course)

Example:

```
StringUtils.hasText(null) == false
StringUtils.hasText("") == false
StringUtils.hasText(" ") == false
StringUtils.hasText("12345") == true
StringUtils.hasText(" 12345 ") == true
```

Comment: Which StringUtils ?  Please specify the full package name.

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/StringUtils.html

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the other answers, I ran across this because I'm a C# programmer primarily, but trying to keep fresh in Java. I noticed that when I tried to use `StringUtils` my IDE (Eclipse) imported it from `com.mysql.jdbc.StringUtils` which actually has an `isNullOrEmpty(myStringObject)` method.

ex.

`import com.mysql.jdbc.StringUtils;`

`StringUtils.isNullOrEmpty(host)`

Just another alternative for those who already have the MySQL connector referenced in your project, but not the other `StringUtils` library.

Answer (score 2):

```
public static boolean isNull(String str) {
        return str == null ? true : false;
    }

    public static boolean isNullOrBlank(String param) {
        if (isNull(param) || param.trim().length() == 0) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Yashwant, you don't need the return true, return false lines: 
return str==null || str.trim().length()==0;

Comment: `return str == null ? true : false;` - classic no-no. Why not `return str == null`?

Comment: Why even implement the first method when you can write if (str == null)?

Comment: Just a note about the second method, that is not how it is implemented in the Jakarta commons, mainly because when you execute the "trim" method you are creating a new object, and in their implementation they actually traverse the string from the start, and if they find anything else than a space, they will stop the method and return true. It is probably faster and it is likely to be better on memory.

It is a tiny little thing but for these reasons it is better to use an external library.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this method written a few times in projects I've been on but I have to say I've never written it myself, or called it either ... Generally I find null and empty are completely distinct conditions and I have no reason to ever conflate them.

Comment: Editorializing about why it shouldn't be done isn't an answer, unfortunately.

Answer (score -2):

For new projects, I've started having every class I write extend the same base class where I can put all the utility methods that are annoyingly missing from Java like this one, the equivalent for collections (tired of writing list != null && ! list.isEmpty()), null-safe equals, etc.  I still use Apache Commons for the implementation but this saves a small amount of typing and I haven't seen any negative effects.

Comment: Creating your own "Universal Base Class" is questionable on many counts, and a really limiting design strategy in a language without multiple inheritance.

Comment: Java already has a universal base class called Object. I can extend my base class just as easily as that one.  Like I said, I haven't seen any problems yet, but I'm interested in hearing about the potential pitfalls - maybe I'll submit an S/O question asking about it.

Comment: I'm not taking a position here, but I think the limitation ("break down") would be if one of *your* classes needed to inherit from some *library* class, such as a GUI control etc. Those classes of yours would then have no direct way of inheriting and using your utility methods (unlike Object, your MyObject is not a superclass of everyone else's classes). @DonRoby, is that what you meant? Is there a specific danger here, as long as one isn't relying on, say, MyObject overriding standard methods that Object defines?

Comment: @JCoombs, Yes that's pretty much what I meant.

Comment: See discussion here: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/273305/why-is-base-for-all-objects-discouraged-in-c