# How to check null for getter methods in java

Tags: java

I have a POJO class.

```
class Activity{
   private String name;

   public String getName()
      return name;
   }

   public void setName(String name){
      this.name=name;
   }
}
```

im having belw condtions.its not enr=ering properly in those condtions accordingly

```
 if(stlmtTransRequestVO.getStlmtTransId()!=null && stlmtTransRequestVO.getPaymentTransId()!=null){
stlmtTransDtlsList = (List<StlmtTransResponseVO>) queryForList(
        "GET_STLMTPAY_TRANSACTIONS", stlmtTransRequestVO);


 }else if(stlmtTransRequestVO.getAgentId()!=null && stlmtTransRequestVO.getAgencyId()==null){
stlmtTransDtlsList = (List<StlmtTransResponseVO>) queryForList(
        "GET_AGENT_TRANSACTIONS", stlmtTransRequestVO);

 }else if(stlmtTransRequestVO.getAgencyId()!=null && stlmtTransRequestVO.getAgentId()==null){
stlmtTransDtlsList = (List<StlmtTransResponseVO>) queryForList(
        "GET_AGENCY_TRANSACTIONS", stlmtTransRequestVO);

 }else if(stlmtTransRequestVO.getAgencyId()!=null && stlmtTransRequestVO.getAgentId()!=null){

}
```

How to check this getter method for having data or not?

I have tried below scenarios but not working

```
   1) obj.getName()!=null
   2) obj.getName().isEmpty()
```

Comment: What result did you expect and what did you get?

Comment: Please post fully compilable source code here. Currently your code has compiler errors. And I'm sure, if you remove those errors, you are done. Because your 1st way is correct way for null check.

Comment: Any errors when "not working"?

Comment: just as a sidenote, but make sure your obj is also not null

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2272169/string-isnullorempty-in-java

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
if( obj.getName() != null && !"".equals(obj.getName()) ){
   //getName is valid
}
```

Above is checking that name is **not null** and also it's **not empty**. Also **"".equals(obj.getName())** is considered better approach than **obj.getName().equals("")**.

Comment: What happens if have 30 strings like that. How do i check all is null or not?

Comment: Iterate through all of them and check.

Comment: Is `!"".equals(obj.getName())` any different than using `!obj.getName().isEmpty`?

Comment: you need to implement isEmpty() method.

Answer (score 12):

`obj.getName() != null` is right. But it depends on your definition of "having data". It might be: `object.getName() != null && !obj.getName().isEmpty()`.

There are utilities to facilitate that, like apache commons-lang `StringUtils.isNotEmpty(..)`

Answer (score 3):

Initialize like this:

```
private String name = "";
```

Then you can check it with:

```
obj.getName().isEmpty();
```

Answer (score 1):

Your first check is correct. Modify your 2nd check as follows:

```
obj.getName().equals("");
```

Comment: what if getName() is null?

Comment: There is no difference between the 2nd check and the modified one you posted.

Comment: in 1st check he's doing it.

Comment: he does not place an "and" between those scenarios (so i suspect they are separate checks); the null check should be there all the time, imho

Comment: @RohitJain: He wanted to check for empty string. and i told the correct way.

Comment: @Azodious.. `String#isEmpty()` does the same.

Comment: @RohitJain: Ohhh .. yes. i totally ignored that method. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Name is a String object, to check if it hasn´t data do this:

```
obj.getName() != null;
obj.getName.equals("");
```

Answer (score 1):

Always Use [StringUtils.isEmpty](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#isEmpty-java.lang.CharSequence-) in case of String