# Create a method "addNumberEnd(String password)" in java?

Tags: java, arrays, string

I would like to create a array method "addNumberEnd(String password)" that returns and stores a string that has an added number(0-9) at the end of the string. For example, I have a string "mike" and I want it to return "mike0", "mike1" until "mike9". So, if I want to retrieve array[2], I would retrieve "mike2".

Comment: Give it a shot so. In all seriousness, make an attempt, follow online tutorials/ask your teacher and come back with a *specific* problem if it's still not working.

Comment: You're not asking a question here. With what exactly do you want help?

Comment: Please show us your code and what you attempted so far. StackOverflow is not a 'Write my code for me' service.

Comment: since you have already know what you want to do. you need be patient on thinking how to achieve it. It's quite simple if you believe you can make it.

Comment: I'm sorry if I broke any rules here. This is my first time posting a question here and yes my "question" does not sound like a question. I am actually struggling with this method because I did try to solve this myself. I should've asked in a well-mannered way. I am sorry if I offended anyone.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use a Map ?

```
void addNumberEnd(String password,Map<Integer,String> myMap){
     if(myMap!=null)
        myMap.put(myMap.size(),password);
}
```

And then just get your String by :

```
String password = myMap.get(myNumber);
if(password != null)
   password = password + " " + myNumber;
```

edit : works for a type of password, you need to have n hashmap for n differents passwords

Comment: Don't answer this kind of requirement post. That person is just expecting you to do his job. Even if what you do is full of good intention, it will only increase the occurrence of those "question". Not all question should be answered ;)

Comment: just want to get points, because I can't comment, stackoverflow process

Comment: I understand, but this is not a reason to break the rules. If you get caught driving above the speed limit at destination, even if you tell the cops it was to arrive sooner, this was still breaking the rule. Slow down, try answering good question, you will get the reputation soon enough.

Comment: I'm sorry if I broke any rules here. This is my first time posting a question here and yes my "question" does not sound like a question. I am actually struggling with this method because I did try to solve this myself. I should've asked in a well-mannered way. I am sorry if I offended anyone.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever I got from your description is you want code but this is not the place to provide you code from scratch, still I am writing some pseudo code. hope this helps....

1. you have to check if the string is null or empty, if it is then return enpty Array or error.
2. if not empty, declare Array String [] passwordArray = new Array[10]
3. Satrt for loop  for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
4. add value to array passwordArray[i] = password+i
5. end for loop
6. return array.

Answer (score -1):

You should not ask for code here, no one will do your work for you.
Still, i'll try to help you.

Using @nIKHIL 's answer as an example, i'd suggest you to check the isEmpty method for Strings, or make your own one. ([Here are some examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2272169/string-isnullorempty-in-java)).

And use a loop to append a number to the string, once it's done done return the array.

Comment: I'm sorry if I broke any rules here. This is my first time posting a question here and yes my "question" does not sound like a question. I am actually struggling with this method because I did try to solve this myself. I should've asked in a well-mannered way. I am sorry if I offended anyone.

Comment: You didn't offend anyone, so don't worry. But you can't ask other people to code for you. If it wasn't the intention then don't worry about it, just rephrase it. :)